# select login name items from list client object model

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, client-object-model

I don't get the title, or any item in the `get_Vote_onSuccess` function
see below the code:

```
var ctx;
var collListItem;
var web;
var loginUser;
$(document).ready(function () {
    SP.SOD.executeOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(GetVoteUser, "SP.js");
    function GetVoteUser() {
        try {
            ctx = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
            web = ctx.get_web();
            ctx.load(web);
            var user = web.get_currentUser();
            user.retrieve();
            ctx.executeQueryAsync(function () {
                var index = user.get_loginName().indexOf('|') + 1;
                loginUser = user.get_loginName().substring(index);
                alert(loginUser);
                ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(selectList(loginUser), "sp.js");
            }, function (data) {
                alert("failed");
            });
        }
        catch (e) {
            alert("error occurred" + e.toString());
        }
    }

});
function selectList(loginUser) {
    ctx = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    web = ctx.get_web();
    ctx.load(web);
    var oList = web.get_lists().getByTitle('dinner on us vote');
    var camlQuery = new SP.CamlQuery();
    camlQuery.set_viewXml('<View Scope=\'RecursiveAll\'>' +
                '<Query>' +
                    '<Where>' +
                    '<Eq>' +
                        '<FieldRef Name=\'Author\' />' +
                        '<Value Type=\'LookUp\'>' + loginUser + '</Value>' +
                    '</Eq>' +
                    '</Where>' +
                '</Query>' +
                     '</View>');

    collListItem = oList.getItems(camlQuery);
    ctx.load(collListItem);

    ctx.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.get_Vote_onSuccess),
        Function.createDelegate(this, this.get_Vote_onFailure));
}
function get_Vote_onFailure() {
    alert("An error occurred while fetching data. Please contact your system administrator.");
}
function get_Vote_onSuccess() {
    alert(collListItem.Items.count());
    var listItemEnumerator = collListItem.getEnumerator();
    while (listItemEnumerator.moveNext()) {
        var item = listItemEnumerator.get_current();
        var title = item.get_item('Title');
        alert(title);
        alert("hghghghgh");
    }
}
```

Comment: What is `user.retrieve()`? I don't see the user object being loaded anywhere, so that's why you're not getting any user data.

Comment: Check developer console (F12) and see if you are getting an error anywhere.

Comment: thanks,i am getting the user name this row give me my user name alert(loginUser); but the function selectList return sucess but any data and any error on page

Comment: the user object is being good and alert(loginUser); is working fine the problem is in the function selectList, I am debugging and its return to the success function but any object retrieve.

Comment: now i am getting data from list...but how i can get the format from login name to "jon rash" i am getting domain\jonr and in the list the Author filed is return like "jon rash" any idea?

Comment: the login name is shows as domainname\username and the Author field retrieved Full name can we format something to get much?